# How to add svn parent on local workspace

Tags: svn

I have a setup like

> /trunk
>
> ```
>    /module1
>    /module2
> ```

I have have done:

`svn co /trunk/module1 xxx/module1`

as well as a

`svn co /trunk/module2 xxx/module2`

and now actually want the xxx to be mapped to the trunk, without checking out the whole thing again.  ie like i did a `svn co /trunk xxx`

Ideas?

UPDATE: the only thing that i have found is to do a `svn co --depth=immediate /trunk yyy`
Then copy the .svn folder over to xxx ... seems to work but not sure if that is safe or not?

Answer (score 0):

I had tried with lots of options around `--non-recursive` , `--set-depth` and `--depth` for checkout and update and I don't think it is possible. You will have to checkout afresh for them to be treated as a part of a single working copy.

Comment: Thanks.  Ya i've been fooling around with the same settings as you described. The only thing that i got to work i've added as an update. That should work.